# How make in TypeScript typesafe union type form function

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a function that accept a single value or array of values and depending on it return new values, single or array. Then this value check on type and can't determinate that return value single or array.

How make that TypeScript understand that current value that I pass to function an array and returned values will be array?

```
  prepareForResponseMany2(data: ProductEntity | ProductEntity[]): ProductType | ProductType[] {
    if (Array.isArray(data)) {
      return data.map(entity => this.prepareForResponse(entity));
    }

    return this.prepareForResponse(data);
  }
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you need to use [function overloading](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#overloads) to achieve what you want. So you can create an interface, for instance:

```
  prepareForResponseMany2(data: ProductEntity, ): ProductType;
  prepareForResponseMany2(data: ProductEntity[], ): ProductType[];
  prepareForResponseMany2(data: any): ProductType | ProductType[] {
    if (Array.isArray(data)) {
      return data.map(entity => this.prepareForResponse(entity));
    }

    return this.prepareForResponse(data);
  }
```

In this case, the type of returning value will depend on the type of argument passed into the method.

Comment: I think adding an example of the actual solution would be more helpful

Comment: actually, declaring `any` will allow invalid values to be returned. It should be ```prepareForResponseMany2(data: ProductEntity | ProductEntity[]) { ... }```

Comment: It actually doesn't, the last overload should be wide. I just checked it, you can't pass any value to the method and as a result, you always get the correct return type.

Comment: you are correct about the input type, not about the return type. if it's `any` the function can return anything and there will be no compile warning: [see](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBACgTgewCYFcDGwCiA7YBLUKAXigG8AoKKqAZwQFsJgALPbAcwC4oAjBBADYQAhtnIBfcqEixEqDABVw0EhWq0GTVh259BIsZPIAzFNgx4E2KGDgQwwuwDEEcAEoQaYKzQgBZURAAJgAKJGFgYW54ZHQsXAIQAEpouTilGRMzCysbOwdnVw8vH39A0PDI1NiMHHxQAG0AXRTZGuAMiGbyLPN8XNt7RwgXd09vbF8A7GCwiKioQNbAskpqO2AUOGsAdjWjciA)

Comment: You are the best!!

Comment: @thedude yes, I see. I updated it to the union type. Thank you for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `(someValue as ProductType[])` or `(<ProductType[]>someValue)`

[Type assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions)

Comment: So there is no solution to make ts resolve it automatically? Because I need to write it every time